# Is it possible to use GeneratePathProperty from nuget package installed in a dependant project?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I've a c# solution with 2 projects in .net framework 4.8: ProjectA and ProjectB.

ProjectA has installed a nuget package, called NugetPackageInternal package that exports a contentFile: NugetPackageInternalFile.

ProjectB depends on ProjectA and needs to use the NugetPackageInternalFile

To use NugetPackageInternalFile in ProjectB I've added this into ProjectB.csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)\NugetPackageInternal\0.0.1\contentFiles\any\any\NugetPackageInternalFile">
      <Link>TestData\NugetPackageInternalFile</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works but, whenever there is new version of NugetPackageInternal I need to manually change ProjectB.csproj to update the 0.0.X version.

To fix this the only way I found is to install the NugetPackageInternal also into ProjectB and add the GeneratePathProperty=true, so my ProjectB.csproj looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NugetPackageInternal" GeneratePathProperty="true">
      <Version>0.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(PkgNugetPackageInternal)\contentFiles\any\any\NugetPackageInternalFile">
      <Link>TestData\NugetPackageInternalFile</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works fine also, but my question would be: Is there a way to refer NugetPackageInternalFile from ProjectA and avoid to install the NugetPackageInternal into ProjectB?

Adding GeneratePathProperty=true into ProjectA PackageReference doesn't work.